# Where do I put the files I want to be displayed on my webpage on my webhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting, web-hosting, bluehost

So I just finished the railstutorial.org twitter clone example and I want to put it online with my web hosting provider bluehost. Right now all I have is a file called sample_app with all of the rails stuff in it. And it works fine when I visit it on localhost:3000.

So I go to my bluehost file manager and there are 9 different folders, like public_html, public_ftp, rails_apps, www, tmp, access_logs, ect. Ive uploaded sample_app into this overall directory and into the public_html directory itself. But when I visit my website it just displays the html in a default.html file in the public_html directory.

What exactly is telling my hosting service to use public_html/default.html of any of the hundereds of different files and folders that are in other places on my server space? How do I find this thing and tell it to instead use sample_app or public_html/sample_app and then process everything in that to display my rails application?

Ive tried using bluehost support and they emailed me and said this would be accomplished by creating a symlink which links ~/rails_apps/NinetyNine/public to ~/public_html. I have no idea how to do this and the guides I find online all tell me to enter a series of commands. I dont know whether to do this in a terminal on my ubuntu system or some command prompt that bluehost provides. If it is at a terminal on my system which directory should I be in? any attempts I have made on my system have resulted in a no such file or directory error. When I asked bluehost to explain this they said that this was outside of the scope of their support and had to do with web development not hosting. It struck me as odd that they were unwilling to explain their own response to my problem but whatever.

If anyone of you could  help me or point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. What is telling my hosting service to use `public_html/default.html` ?

   That would be a setting the web server configuration, probably Apache.

   In Apache's case, the `public_html` directory is usually enabled with the
   [`UserDir`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/public_html.html) directive.

   The `default.html`, is also an Apache configuration, [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html).

   Answering these because you asked: but typically, the global Apache configuration
   is maintained by your provider (though you usually have some means to customize
   parts of it).
2. Create the symlink from `public_html` to

   They like gave you a command like (maybe not exactly)

   ```
   $ ln -s ~/rails_apps/NinetyNine/public public_html
   ```

   That is something that is intended to be run on your webhost, from a command prompt,
   at the top of your home directory.

   Look for docs on bluehost for finding out how to get SSH shell access.
   That's where you'll enter the command.
3. More generally, however, you want to make sure you read the docs on how your
   provider wants you to upload applications. Bluehost seems to have very nice
   docs here:

   https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/rails
4. Why your hosting provided said it was out of scope.

   You're a beginner, and that's officially OK. Welcome!

   But if you asked them a question like "Do I enter these commands on my computer
   or yours", they are definitely going to politely respond that this out of scope;
   meaning -- "We can't hand-hold you through this". If you ran a gas station and
   someone asked you how to use the pump, you'd tell them. But if they then asked
   "OK but do I put the gas in my car or yours?" you'd be reluctant to answer, because
   there's some fundamental missing.
5. So how do I get more pointers, directions on this stuff?

   Lots of approaches. By the far the best is to do as much stuff as you can on 
   your own computer. In your case, you could easily set up your own Apache
   (Macs and Linux frequently ship with it - readily installable on Windows), and
   that would clear up a lot of the conceptual issues.

Good luck!